# Java bufferreader crashes on ctrl z

Tags: java

I'm making a game which plays until the user enters quit in the command line.

The user can enter different commands like get and go, with the get command the user can say what to get like, get baseball bat. What I do in my code is split the command.

everything is working fine but I have found a bug which I can't solve. If I enter "get" and press <kbd>space</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> it gets in a while loop which never ends.

It only happens with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (1 time with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> but after that 1 time not anymore)

```
 private void run() 
{       
    while (! quitCommand)
    {
        
        String input = null;
        
        try 
        {   
            input = null;
            System.out.println("Input "+ input);
            System.out.println("Give a command.");
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            input = is.readLine();
            handleCommand(input);
            // As long as the command isn’t to quit:
            // get the next input line and handle it. (With handleCommand.)
        } 
        
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong we are sorry try again.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}

/**
* @param userInput (This is the entire input string from the user.)
*
* (Tell others to) Perform the task which belongs to the given
* command.
*/
private void handleCommand(String userInput) 
{
    
    
    // Split the user input string.
    if (userInput != null)          // user input can not be empty
    {
        String[] delenTekst = userInput.split(" ");
        
        // The first word is a command. The rest is extra information
        String command = delenTekst[0];
        String extra = "";
        
        for (int i = 1; i < delenTekst.length; i ++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                extra = extra + delenTekst[i];
            }
            else
            {
                extra = extra +" " + delenTekst[i];
            }               
        }

        switch (command)
        {
            // Check if the command is to travel between rooms. If so, handle
            case "go"
            : 
                this.checkRoomTravel(extra);
                break;
            // If there isn't any room travel, then check all other command
            case "get"
            :   
                System.out.println("Looking for " +extra );
                this.handleGetCommand(extra);
                break;
            case "quit"
            :
                quitCommand = true;
                break;
            default
            :
                System.out.println("Command is not known try help for information");
                break;  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        userInput = "help";
    }
}
```

I'm new to java so it can be something really simple.

On the top of my script I have a private boolean `quitCommand = false;` which is to check if the user entered quit.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Ctrl-z means something different on windows than it does linux.

Comment: im using windows 7 64 bit im running the program in the console of eclipse

Comment: Well on windows Ctrl-z means end of file. If the eclipse console is just an incarnation of the windows command line (which I'm not sure that it is) then the buffered reader may be getting Ctrl-z and assuming that's the end of the file. Does your while loop spew out "Command is not known try help for information"?

Comment: Nope if i pres ctrl + z it gets in a while wich returns loop Input null
Give a command.
Input null
Give a command.
Input null
Give a command.
Input null
Give a command.
Input null
Give a command. So it dosnt give any errors but i cant get out of the loop, it dosnt stop to wait for input anymore

Comment: I guess that makes sense. You could break if the string = `null` but I'm not sure what the desired behavior is.

Comment: I want the console to ask for input until the quit command is give, there can be commands with paramters like get baseball bet

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39564/discussion-between-sven-b-and-osmium-usa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> closes the Console and therefore your `readLine()` returns null as pretended to indicate that end of file was reached. So all you need to do, is to check for `null` returned by `readLine()` and handle this as you handle the "quit".

I've changed your code (just to test my thesis) and also stream lined a few things, e.g. you dont need to recreate a `BufferedReader` every time you read a line.

```
private boolean quitCommand = false;
 private void runIt() {       
     BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     String input = null;

     while(!quitCommand) {
         try {   
             System.out.print("Give a command: ");
             input = is.readLine();

             // As long as the command isn’t to quit:
             if(input == null || "quit".equals(input.trim())) quitCommand = true;
             if(quitCommand) break;

             // get the next input line and handle it. (With handleCommand.)
             String[] words = input.trim().split("\\s+");

             // ** This is the original handleCommand line **
             System.out.println(input + ":" + Arrays.toString(words));
         } 
         catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Something went wrong we are sorry try again.");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

BTW: To split the input into words I'd use the regular expression as shown in my code. This works also if the user enters tabs or multiple spaces.

Comment: You check `input == null` but in the next line you have `input.trim()` This will just NPE.  I would just `break;` when finished.

Comment: Me too. I changed the code. I wouldn't use the `quitCommand` myself, but I also didn't want to change too much on the code.

Comment: Thanks this helped me. but the game will crash if the user press ctrl + z (crash = quit the game) it isnt possible to avoid this? fault of windows ?

Comment: When pressing ctrl-Z `System.in` - the Console - itself is closed and I havent seen any way to reopen it again while in the process. Same thing happens on Linux, Unix, MAC. If you would like to avoid this behavior, you need to listen to key events rather then reading from console. You can write a little Java-Swing program because there special keys like ctrl-z are covered.

Comment: Last question (accepted it already) what dos   "quit".equals(input.trim()) exactly do? and why arent there {} after the if statements? Thx for the help

Comment: The {} are not necessary because only the one next statement belongs to the `if`. The {} are only necessary to group more statement together. The `equals` statement takes the input, trims leading and trailing spaces and compares that to the word "quit". You could use lowercase to it so that the user can mix lower an uppercase letters. I like to start a comparison with the constant. A very old behavior from Pascal times (Yes, I'm that old :-)

Answer (score 0):

On DOS/Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> means end of input.  This causes readLine() to return `null` no matter how many times you call it.  This is likely to cause your code to fail as you don't appear to check for it.  I suspect you are getting a NullPointerException which you are pretending didn't happen and trying again, endlessly.

Comment: dosnt  if (userInput != null)          // user input can not be empty
    { code} else {userInput = "help"} avoid that?

Comment: It avoids the NPE, but it doesn't break the loop.  You are not testing userInput in your loop so setting it doesn't do anything.